# ListLogPlot for positive and negative values

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am trying to plot the following set of points on Mathematica:

```
xp = {{0, 0.8846000933830923`}, {2, -0.012970915604651983`}, {4, 
    0.0000949016045027063`}, {6, -4.618329266942706`*^-7}, {8, 
    1.6813297661229669`*^-9}, {10, -4.883992575253075`*^-12}}
```

Using ListLogPlot gets rid of the negative values; is there a simple fix for this?

Edit: using

```
ScalingFunctions -> {None, {"SignedLog", 10^-12}}
```

did the trick, thank you Bob Hanlon for the recommendation.

Comment: What do you expect to be plotted for x = 2, y = log(-0.01297...)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I would like the ticks to be equally spaced, displaying 0,10^-1,-10^-1,10^-2, -10^-2, and so on, so the values positive values "appear" to be linear, negative values "appear" to be linear.

Comment: Wouldn't the distance between 10^-2 and -10^-2 be infinite on a logarithmic scale?

Comment: @MichaelE2 It's not really defined there in the first place, but I would like to artificially place tick marks that denote -10^-2 in a manner that puts the second point visually below y=0 with equal spacing as 10^-2 is from 0 (when in logarithmic scale)

Comment: `ListPlot[xp, ScalingFunctions -> "SignedLog"]` is one approach, but it clips the values at `x==0` and `x==2` and the very small magnitude values look like they're on the axis.

Answer (score 0):

This could be made nicer, but how about something like this?

```
GraphicsColumn[{
  ListLogPlot[Select[xp, #[[2]] > 0 &], PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, All}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]],
  ListLogPlot[Abs[Select[xp, #[[2]] < 0 &]], 
   ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse", PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, All}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], AxesOrigin -> {0, 10^-12}, 
   Ticks -> {{{10.^-11, -10.^-11}, {10.^-8, -10.^-8}, {10.^-5, \
-10.^-5}, {10.^-2, -10.^-2}}}]
}]
```

[image]